# React form submittal and Django POST request

Tags: django, python-2.7, reactjs, django-forms, axios

I need help identifying the bug in my current code. Few things to note:

1. Admin server validates model exist however the admin dashboard displays empty fields.
2. Client side: form submits successfully and captures data in state
3. I am not using a forms.py only because I did not understand the use case for it.

My issue is being able to collect the data from the client and send it to the api. My request.POST object returns empty even though the rest of the app seems to be working. I want the data from the React form to POST to the Django server.

Things I have tried:

1. changing django.views.generic from TemplateView to FormView to View
2. change path to template ./djangorest/template/index.html

views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from api.models import Risk


class create_user(TemplateView):

def index(self, request):
    template = 'index.html'
    return render(request, self.template)



def post(self, request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        risk_type = request.POST.get('risk_type')
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
        age = request.POST.get('age')
        zipCode = request.POST.get('zipCode')
        prize_amount = request.POST.get('prize_amount')
        currency = request.POST.get('currency')

        Risk.objects.create(
            risk_type = risk_type,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            age = age,
            zipCode = zipCode,
            prize_amount = prize_amount,
            currency = currency
        )

        return redirect('/')

        print('*'*50)
        print(request.POST)
        print('*'*50)


    return HttpResponse("<h1>Submitted</h1>")
```

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import datetime
from django.utils import timezone


from django.db import models

class Risk(models.Model):
    risk_type = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    zipCode = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    prize_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True,   null=True)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
```

urls.py ==> /djangorest/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from api import views

from django.contrib import admin
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', include('api.urls')),
    url(r'^$',
      generic.TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name="home")

]
```

urls.py ==> /api/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.create_user.as_view(), name='create-user'),
]
```

index.html ==> templates/ index.html

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    {% render_bundle 'main' %}
    {% csrf_token %}
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Data is valid object]

[image]

Comment: So, when you submit the form you `console.log` the data. The names of the data are camelCase (`riskType` etc). Then, you try to retrieve those data with `request.POST.get('risk_type')` instead of `request.POST.get('riskType')` etc. Maybe, that's the issue?

Comment: @nik_m thanks for the suggestion! I was thinking, if the naming convention was the issue then "age", "currency" and "zipCode" would have posted to the api but they did not. Anyway, I tried your suggestion and it did not work. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: OK. Then, would you mind to show your `index.html` and, possibly, your `forms.py` files?

Comment: @nik_m hey I made some updates to my original post. Also, I am not using a forms.py. This is my first React-Django project and I did not understand the use for forms.py.

Comment: Seems that `TemplateView` is wrong. Why not inherit from [`FormView`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/), instead? This class implements the `post()` method, while `TemplateView` not.

Answer (score 0):

here are some notes I hope they help:

django-form creates some HTML and CSS for your input fields but in reactjs,
we write JSX for creating our input fields which are similar to HTML you can read about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html).

In React our interactions with the server are with ajax. you simply send an ajax request to the server and get a response without refreshing the page and this interaction is with [JSON format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). in the backend, you have to return JSON too. whether with Django helper methods or third-party libraries like django-rest-framework.

please be sure that you are sending a POST request to the server because you have a condition on that in your view.

if these notes didn't make it please show the request that you are receiving in your view with

```
print(request)
```

ps: you can use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) for fast testing your view.